# How can I retrieve information about a line drawn with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to analyze lines already drawn on the plot with for cycle. I tried using `ax.get_lines()[0].get_data()` function but no matter what kind of line (which points it passes through) I draw, it returns `([0, 1], [0, 1])` as the data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.00, 7.00]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim([0, 100])
ax.set_ylim([0, 100])

point1 = [-8,4]
point2 = [10,15]
plt.axline(point1,point2) # drawing the line

lines = ax.get_lines()
print(lines[0].get_data()) # retrieving data

plt.show()
```

Comment: when i use the code given i get a line that goes from `(0, 10)` to `(100, 70)`. So it looks like it is working.   what are you expecting ?

Comment: Are (-8,4) and (10,15) the two endpoints of your line or just two points on your line?

Comment: @jared,  it does not matter if they are points or end points. the `slope` and `intercept` parameters can be computer either way....

Comment: @D.L I'm asking because they're using `axline`, but if these are the endpoints then they can use `plot`, which stores the data they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i looked at the usage of `get_lines()` in various resources and it seems to be used to get the number of lines (in the literature. like this:

```py
lines = ax.get_lines()
print('number of lines', len(lines))
```

if you want to get the description (*presumably slope and intercept*) of a (*straight*) line between two points you can make a simple function like this to achieve the outcome:

```py
def get_slope_and_intercept(point1, point2):
    """
    Gets the slope and intercept of the line given point1 and point2 as two lists.

    Args:
        point1: The first point, as a list of two numbers.
        point2: The second point, as a list of two numbers.

    Returns:
        A tuple of the slope and intercept of the line.
    """

    x1, y1 = point1
    x2, y2 = point2

    slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
    intercept = y1 - slope * x1

    return slope, intercept


if __name__ == "__main__":

    slope, intercept = get_slope_and_intercept(point1, point2)

    print("The slope is:", slope)
    print("The intercept is:", intercept)
```

With the points that are given in the question, it would produce this:

```
The slope is: 0.6111111111111112
The intercept is: 8.88888888888889
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that I want to analyze multiple lines together after they are already drawn with for cycle. I thought that if there is a Line2D object for each line drawn then maybe the information about its slope and intercept can be retrieved. If it isn't possible I will probably have to save this data manually.

Comment: You might have missed it but I used get_data() function after get_lines() and it presumably has to return some x and y values for the line. But in my code it always returns the same ([0, 1], [0, 1]) no matter what line is considered

Comment: if you want a description of the line than you can use `label=f'{point1}, {point2}` in the plot.   then you can use `line.get_label()` to achieve this.  I will modify the answer accordingly if you think that is helpful....

Comment: @ximik717,  i just made a really nice bit of code (to do the above), but glad you got there on your own.  Basically, in summary, the rule is to use `labels` to describe lines.

Answer (score 0):

When using `axline`, the supplied coordinates are stored in `line._xy1` and `line._xy2` (similarly, the slope data is stored in `line._slope`, but this will be `None` if you don't use this argument).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

point1 = [-8,4]
point2 = [10,15]
ax.axline(point1, point2)

lines = ax.get_lines()
print(lines[0]._xy1, lines[0]._xy2)    # [-8, 4] [10, 15]
```

This is different from a line produced using the normal `plot` function where you can use `line.get_xydata()` to get the data. I'm not entirely sure why `[0,1]` was used, but that is hardcoded into the [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/lib/matplotlib/lines.py) (look at the `_AxLine` class where the `super.__init__` is called for the `Line2D` class with `[0,1]` passed for both the `x` and `y` data).